# Is it possible to inject some javascript in React Native without updating the entire bundle?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have used libraries like Codepush to update the the App over the air.However, with Codepush the new bundle is built and then existing one is replaced with the new one .
I wanted to change some javascript code for a component (maybe using an API or anything else wherein I can inject some javascript file from the server) without updating the existing bundle .

For eg=> If I have a simple UI wherein top half is empty.
The injected Javascript file (child component in the top half of the UI) may contain some Component and its handlers (can be a button or image or textinput field,etc).

This injected file is loaded as a component from the server, so I can dynamically change the component from the server file itself.
Is there any particular way to do this?

Comment: eval, u can use.

Comment: eval will only help execute javascript . When accessing imports and React-Native Api's it will throw an error

Comment: u can get string html using ajax call and eval.

Comment: Yup .HTML would work but none of the React Native Api's.Thanks.

Comment: react native is javascript bind.. if u have class and method already loaded. It mean it will work. Think like dynamically creating UI. I tried before and it was working. But eval hard to get control. so we dump idea. u can look at code-push..https://microsoft.github.io/code-push/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### It's unlikely that you're able to push a file into an already transpiled and minimized bundle.

The better option would be to make an API call from your frontend to your backend to retrieve dynamic data. This data can then be manipulated and shown on your frontend.

Then all you need to do to change what is shown on your frontend is to change what your API returns from your backend.

EDIT:
`If the component initially loaded is a simple button and post api response it turns into a modal wherein the entire modal UI as well as event handler code comes in from the API response as a component .Is something like that possible?`

#### No.

You cannot send an uncompiled component to the front end. Remember the bundle that is given to the client is transpiled minified javascript. You cannot conditionally recompile the application for a single user, or if you could - seems like an incredibly bad idea.

What you could do is allow your frontend to receive and render HTML content from an API call. No recompiling has to happen, however you won't be able to use React Classes etc. It would have to be pure HTML/CSS/Javascript.

Comment: This makes sense . However, what if the data to be shown in the front end is a component? Some UI to be rendered which will dynamically keep changing as per the changes made in the backend file (API response file.) . For eg-> If the component initially loaded is a simple button and post api response it turns into a modal wherein the entire modal UI as well as event handler code comes in from the API response as a component .Is something like that possible?

Comment: @AbhijeetKhairnar It sounds like what you want is a real browser, not react native. This is the technique used by software like Steam, iTunes etc.